# Probability density function; is my answer right?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[-1,1]$ and define the random variables $x_{K}=U^{K}$ for $K \in \mathbb{N}$ find the probability density function on $x_k$.

**Answer** the pdf is the derivative of the cdf which is $$F_{x_k}=P\bigg(U\in\bigg[-y^{\frac{1}{k}},y^{\frac{1}{k}}\bigg]\bigg)=y^{\frac{1}{k}}$$ so the pdf is $$f_{x_k}=\frac{1}{k}y^{\frac{1}{k}-1}$$ However the question gives a hint to look at $k$ odd and even separately so I'm assuming I've done something wrong.

Comment: When $k$ is even, $U\in\left[-y^{1/k},y^{1/k}\right] = U\in\left[0,y^{1/k}\right]$, so your answer is correct. But $k$ is odd, ${\mathbb P}\left(U\in\left[-y^{1/k},y^{1/k}\right]\right)=2y^{1/k}$.

Comment: Also check the domain of $y$, it also depends on whether $k$ is odd or even...

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I'm not 100% sure why it should be $2y^{1/k}$ for k is odd

Comment: Look at the range of your interval...

Comment: When doing questions like this, especially as a novice probabilist, it is very important to explicitly state where the density is 0 and where it is non-zero. Doing this avoids many problems, such as what you are encountering here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $F$ denotes the CDF of $U^k$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

1) $k$ is even.

Then $0\leq U^k\leq1$ a.s. so that $F(y)=0$ for $y<0$, $F(y)=1$ for $y\geq1$ and for $y\in(0,1)$:$$U^k\leq y\iff -y^{\frac1k}\leq U\leq y^{\frac1k}\text{ hence }F(x)=\frac12\cdot2y^{\frac1k}=y^{\frac1k}$$

Give this a sanity check for e.g. $k=2$.

2) $k$ is odd.

Then $-1\leq U^k\leq1$ a.s. so that $F(y)=0$ for $y<-1$, $F(y)=1$ for $y\geq1$ and for $y\in(0,1)$:$$U^k\leq y\iff U\leq y^{\frac1k}\text{ hence }F(x)=\frac12\cdot(y^{\frac1k}+1)$$

Give this a sanity check for e.g. $k=1$.

The PDF can be found easily as derivative of the CDF.